# Accessing the AppStore through Notifications Edit

Tags: macos, mac-appstore, notifications

If I go to system preferences on my MacBook Pro then the App Store I have to unlock it to access it. I was in notifications then clicked on today, then edit and I see the option to click on AppStore button, that takes me to the Appstore with out unlocking it. I do not understand this, so I want to ask if this is normal. I do not have allow access when locked turned on on my iPhone.

Answer (score 2):

The system preferences are locked since some people need to ensure the settings for the app aren’t changed casually.

Launch the App Store application itself from spotlight or the dock or the Apple menu. This avoid the system preference pane that can be locked and unlocked or messing with editing the notifications settings.

Comment: I think the AppStore in Notifications was taking you to the App Store itself. You don't need a password to go to App Store, just a password to change your settings.